# Comparison convergence test $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (2n+1)\beta^{-\sqrt{2n+1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Wolfram Alpha tells me that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (2n+1)\beta^{-\sqrt{2n+1}}$$ converges by comparison test for $\beta > 1$, but I'm struggling to find a function to compare it with. Any ideas?

Edit 1 (Motivation): I got to this series because in the paper I link below there is a proposition (2.7) which uses the Dominated Convergence Theorem in the proof, but they don't specify the dominating function. I am using that proposition in my final degree Thesis, so I have to formally proove it, and this is the natural dominance function. This part of my thesis is about the Hermite-Fourier expansions and the heat and Hermite semigroups.

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123603000831

Edit 2 (Current progress): This actually converges by the integral test, but I would like to find a solution using convergence test.

Comment: The fact that Wolfram Alpha tells that comparison test works does not means that other tests don't work...

Comment: The sereis of general term $a_n:=\frac{n}{(\sqrt\beta)^n}$ is convergent (in nfact,you can get an explicit sum here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence). And Comparison test (with limits) would work here.

Comment: Notice $\frac{d}{du}u \beta^{-\sqrt{u}} = (1 - \frac{(\log \beta)\sqrt{u}}{2})\beta^{-\sqrt{u}}$ is negative when $u > \frac{4}{(\log\beta)^2}$. For $n$ large enough, $(2n+1)\beta^{-\sqrt{u}}$ is non-negative and decreasing in $n$. You can apply [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) to deduce the convergence.

Comment: @TitoEliatron Thank you! But I'm not being able to make that sequence work. If my sequence is $b_n = (2n+1)\beta^{-\sqrt{2n+1}}$ and $a_n$ is your general term, the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b_n}{a_n}$ diverges, right?

Comment: @juanriera you're right.... hummm, my comment does not have sense, yet. Forgive it. Sorry.

Comment: @achillehui Thank you! The integral test does work! I'm still looking for a more elegant solution though, the integral goes a bit wild :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
&  \sum_{n=1}^\infty (2n+1)\beta^{-\sqrt{2n+1}} \\\\
& = \sum_{3\le m < \infty,\\\text{m odd}} m\beta^{-\sqrt{m}}\\\\
& < \sum_{m=1}^\infty m\beta^{-\sqrt{m}}\\\\
& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\beta^{-\sqrt{n}}\end{align}$$

So proving the last series converges is sufficient.

We can use the limit comparison test with the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$$

So we need

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n\beta^{-\sqrt{n}}}{\frac{1}{n^2}}$$

$$=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^3}{\beta^{\sqrt{n}}}$$

For convenience, switch to functional form

$$=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^3}{\beta^\sqrt{x}}$$

Then we can do a variable substitution $y=\sqrt{x}$

$$=\lim_{y \to \infty}\frac{y^6}{\beta^y}$$

Repeated use of l'Hopital's rule will reduce the degree of the numerator, leaving the denominator the same except for multiplying by $\ln(\beta)$. So the limit goes to zero, because $\beta>1$.

So since the limit is zero and the bottom series converges, the top series also converges.

Answer (score 1):

If $b > 1$
then,
since
$\dfrac{\log(n)}{\sqrt{n}}
\to 0$,
$\sqrt{2n+1}
\gt 2\log(n)/\log(b)
$
for all large enough $n$,
so

$\begin{array}\\
 b^{-\sqrt{2n+1}}
&=\dfrac1{b^{\sqrt{2n+1}}}\\
&\lt\dfrac1{b^{2\log(n)/\log(b)}}\\
&=\dfrac1{e^{2\log(b)\log(n)/\log(b)}}\\
&=\dfrac1{e^{2\log(n)}}\\
&=\dfrac1{n^2}\\
\end{array}
$

and the sum of these converges.